# Keycloak does not have all the Keys available in the storage

Tags: keycloak

I have created a realm and added new keystore(RS384) in the Providers section

[image]

When I tried authenticate using postman. I am getting below error in Keycloak console

PublicKey wasn't found in the storage. Requested kid: 'Y3RDLAudovJPEU3Z9BMJL3OyuzqsgAj4424CpxnJqkI' . Available kids: '[]'

Kid is available in the Keys section for the Realm. I am not sure what is causing that. Any help on this is so much appreciated

Edit

Client Authentication

[image]

Added JWKS keys from certs endpoint

[image]

In Postman made call to token endpoint with client_assertion which has signed JWT and got response back "Invalid client: Unable to load Public key "
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is I did not add "use":"sig" in the JWKS that is kid is not available

Answer (score 2):

I think you gave wrong a value(or format) of "Private RSA Key" and "X509 Certificate" file when you add the key-store at Keycloak UI.
it is possible to get the public Key for RS384 by Postman and UI.

I demoed with Keycloak 18.0.0 with "ssh-keygen" & "openssl" on Ubuntu.

1. Generate RS384 private key and public key and certification file

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -E SHA384 -m PEM -P "" -f RS384.key
openssl req -new -x509 -key RS384.key -out RS384-cert.pem -days 360
```

it will create three files

```
RS384-cert.pem  <- certification file  
RS384.key  <- private key
RS384.key.pub <- public key
```

2. Add Keystore with 1.'s files
   [image]
3. New Keystore will be created
   [image]
4. Can get Key by Postman
   [image]
5. can compare public key between UI and openssl generated it.
   [image]
6. you can check API call value and JWT creator web site
   with KID and public key

```
https://russelldavies.github.io/jwk-creator/
```

[image]

Comment: Do we need to add Private Key and Certificate while creating a new Keystore. I did not give any Private key and Certificate. I thought it will auto-generate

Comment: I tested both gave files and auto generated(Keysize 4096 & Algorithm RS384).  Both works for getting key by Postmen API call. gave files way more fine control to verify and handle by myself.

Comment: I am able to get in certs endpoint but the problem is happening when I send JWT to token endpoint it says unable to load public key and in the console it gives PublicKey wasn't found in the storage. Requested kid: 'Y3RDLAudovJPEU3Z9BMJL3OyuzqsgAj4424CpxnJqkI' . Available kids: '[]' error

Comment: Can you add more detail information in your question with step by step?
If not how to reproduce your problem. and which Keycloak version are use?

Comment: From your comment "I send JWT to token endpoint". the token end point get the token not send token. It is something wrong.

Comment: I am using singed JWT for client Authentication. I am sending JWT that is signed to token endpoint to get access token.

Comment: Can you shows me a screen capture, I can't figure out  it?

Comment: Thanks for your update but I want to see "In Postman made call to token endpoint with client_assertion which has signed JWT and got response back "Invalid client: Unable to load Public key " part too.

Comment: Thanks for adding postman screen. It is new to me for client_assertion_type and client_assertion parameter. Give me a sometime to investigate it.

Comment: @Kiran, how to get (or create) the "client_assertion"?
The "client_assertion_type" is "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"

Comment: I have written a Java program to generate. It similar to jwt.io where it takes header, payload and signature to generate JWT